# LSTM.weight_ih_l[k] dimensions with proj_size

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

According to Pytorch [LSTM documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) :-

- **~LSTM.weight_ih_l[k]** – the learnable input-hidden weights of the kth layer (W_ii|W_if|W_ig|W_io), of shape (4*hidden_size, input_size) for k = 0. Otherwise, the shape is (4 * hidden_size, num_directions * hidden_size)

My doubt is, why for `k > 0`  the shape for each weight is `(hidden_size, num_directions * hidden_size)`, according to me, shouldn't be `(hidden_size, num_directions * proj_size)`  because the layer above the lowest layer is receiving the input which is the output of the lowest layer which have the shape of `(L, N, num_directions*proj_size)`

**UPDATE**

Indeed, the documentation have mentioned wrong shapes. It will be fixed soon.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/65053)

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed. The OP opened the [Issue #65053](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/65053) that was fixed by [PR #65102](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/65102) (commit [83878e1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/commit/83878e19ff2af39443016beb31952476c9f049d0)).

---

It just happens that the documentation isn't providing all the details in this case, and you're correct. In fact, you can check in the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py#L71-L89) that the shape of `W_ih` is `(4*hidden_size, num_directions * proj_size)` when `proj_size > 0` for `k > 0`:

```py
# [...]
if mode == 'LSTM':
    gate_size = 4 * hidden_size
elif mode == 'GRU':
    gate_size = 3 * hidden_size
elif mode == 'RNN_TANH':
    gate_size = hidden_size
elif mode == 'RNN_RELU':
    gate_size = hidden_size
else:
    raise ValueError("Unrecognized RNN mode: " + mode)

self._flat_weights_names = []
self._all_weights = []
for layer in range(num_layers):
    for direction in range(num_directions):
        real_hidden_size = proj_size if proj_size > 0 else hidden_size
        layer_input_size = input_size if layer == 0 else real_hidden_size * num_directions

        w_ih = Parameter(torch.empty((gate_size, layer_input_size), **factory_kwargs))
        # [...]
```

As you can see, `w_ih` has the shape `(gate_size, layer_input_size)`, where:

- `gate_size` is `4 * hidden_size` for LSTM, and
- `layer_input_size` is

  - `input_size` if `layer == 0` (`layer` is equivalent to `k` in the docs), else
  - `real_hidden_size * num_directions` for `k > 0`, and
- `real_hidden_size = proj_size` if `proj_size > 0`, else it is `hidden_size`.

That is: if `proj_size > 0` and `layer > 0`, `layer_input_size = proj_size * num_directions`, and the shape of `w_ih` will be equal to `(4 * hidden_size, proj_size * num_directions`.

It is worth noting that they do have the following in the documentation:

> If `proj_size > 0` is specified, LSTM with projections will be used. This changes the LSTM cell in the following way. First, the dimension of `h_t` will be changed from `hidden_size` to `proj_size` (dimensions of `W_hi` will be changed accordingly). Second, the output hidden state of each layer will be multiplied by a learnable projection matrix: `h_t = W_hr * h_t`. Note that as a consequence of this, the output of LSTM network will be of different shape as well.

Comment: I have opened the issue on Github for documentation change.

Comment: @Mrityu sounds reasonable... you can provide a link to this question in the issue as well. People usually like to know when something is a cross-post.

Comment: @Mrityu, additionally could you provide the link to the Github issue in your question?

Comment: @Mrityu The PR was merged and the issue fixed. Thanks for reporting it. Edited the answer to let others know the problem no longer exists.